# Proof regarding Subgroup of an Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

Considering the Abelian Group:
$$x*y=x+y+1 \text{ for } x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$$

I would like to prove if $H=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:x\equiv 2\pmod 3\}$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ or not.

My reasoning was to prove if $x-y-1\equiv 2\pmod 3$ is true. Once $-1$ is the identity element:
$$-1*x=-1+x+1 = x = x*-1=x-1+1 $$

I considered $-1\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

$x*y' = x + (-y -2) +1 \implies y' = -y -2$

Considering $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $y\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

\begin{align}
-1\equiv 2\pmod 3 &\implies y(-1)=2\cdot 2\pmod 3 \\
& \implies x+(-y)\equiv 4+2\pmod 3 \\
& \implies x-y\equiv 6\pmod 3 \\
& \implies x-y+(-1)\equiv 6+2\pmod 3 \\
& \implies x-y-1 \equiv 8\pmod 3
\end{align}

Once $8\equiv 2\pmod 3$, we can conclude that $x-y-1 \equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$.

---

I am still confused about how to prove if $H$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ and I am not sure about the approach I have done. Perhaps it does not answer anything and it is totally wrong. In this context what I should have done? What would be better proof?

Comment: I'm a little confused by exactly what you've written, but I think overall you're correct. Let's denote the group by $G$. You've shown that the identity of $G$ is $-1$, and that $x^{-1} = -x-1$ for any $x \in G$. Then, for $H$ the subset of elements congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, you've verified that $-1 \in H$, then you showed that $x,y \in H$ implies $x*y \in H$, and finally you showed that $x \in H$ implies $x^{-1} \in H$. This concludes your proof that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Since $-1\equiv 2\in H$, we have $H\neq\varnothing$.

By definition, $H\subseteq \Bbb Z$.

Let $h,k\in H$. Then $h=2+3a, k=2+3b$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. Now

$$\begin{align}
h\ast(k^{-1})&=(2+3a)\ast((2+3b)^{-1})\\
&=(2+3a)\ast(-2-(2+3b))\\
&=(2+3a)-(4-3b)+1\\
&=-1+3(a+b)\\
&=2+3(a+b-1),
\end{align}$$

which is in $H$ since $a+b-1\in\Bbb Z$. Hence $h\ast(k^{-1})\in H$.

Hence $H\le (\Bbb Z,\ast)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the edit, I was about to ask about it

Comment: You're welcome, @欲しい未来.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: first of all you have to show that $*$ actually is a group operation. An easy way to do this is to recognise that $\Bbb{Z}$ under $*$ is just $\Bbb{Z}$ under $+$ in disguise: with $i$ disguised as $i -1$ (so that the identity element in your group is $-1$). If you unveil the disguise,  $H$ becomes the set of multiples of $3$ which is certainly a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$ (in plain clothes).